# How to write an extension fun to append a string in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writing a practice code about extension fun.

I plan to add a extension fun `myAdd` for String which accept a lambda fun and append the result of the lambda to the String.

For example:

```
var cc="abc".myAdd{"de"}  //I hope to get "abcde", I don't know whether the lambda {"de"} is correct.
```

But the Code A is wrong, how can I fix it ?

**Code A**

```
fun String.myAdd(predicate: (String) -> String): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder(this)
        sb.append(predicate)
        return sb.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are feeling lucky:

```
infix fun String.myAdd(transform: (String) -> String) = this + transform(this)
```

so you can call:

```
"abc" myAdd { "de" }
```

Or skip the infix:

```
fun String.myAdd(transform: (String) -> String) = this + transform(this)
```

and call it by:

```
"abc".myAdd { "de" }
```

which both will result in:

```
"abcde"
```

Note that both solutions allow the current string to be passed to the given transformation function before being added. If you didn't want that in the first place but rather wanted a supplier, then you may want to use the following instead:

```
fun String.myAdd(supplier: () -> String) = this + supplier()
```

still with the same results

Comment: Thanks, there are two 'this' in your code `fun String.myAdd(transform: (String) -> String) = this + transform(this)`,   they point to different object, right?

Comment: No. In this case they are both the same. So using the example it's both times `"abc"`. If you do not want that, you should rather use the bottom version using the supplier.

Comment: The  first `this` point `"abc"` and second `this` point `"de"` in  `"abc".myAdd { "de" }` , right?

Comment: No. Both `this` contain the value `"abc"` and the second `this` within `transform(this)` actually then means `transform("abc")` which then returns only the value `"de"` as the transformation function does nothing with the incoming value, i.e. `{ "de" }`. If it was `{ "$it de" }` instead, you would get: `abcabc de` as a result

Comment: Thanks! it's hard to understand the code `fun String.myAdd(transform: (String) -> String) = this + transform(this)` if two `this` point the same object

Comment: Usually `this` always points to the same object (actually *this* object). However it may get more confusing, if you encounter `apply`-, `run`- or `with`-uses of `this`. Read more about `this` here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly that you wanted to append the result of the lambda to the original String, you should be doing this:

```
fun String.myAdd(predicate: (String) -> String): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder(this)
    sb.append(predicate(this))
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Also, `predicate` is a very confusing name, it should probably be something else, `transform`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, there are two 'this' in your code, they point to different object, right?

Comment: using of StringBuilder just for append a string once is totally useless way, this is bad example

Answer (score 2):

```
fun String.add(append: () -> String) = this + append()
```

Usage:

```
val str = "hello".add {
    "world"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't nee to pass a function, you can just pass a simple `String`:

```
fun String.myAdd(predicate: String): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder(this)
        sb.append(predicate)
        return sb.toString()
}
```

However, I don't think it makes sense to create a `Stringbuilder` here.
But if it's just a tutorial then that's fine.

**Update 1**

And if you need the lambda it would be somethink like:

```
fun String.myAdd(predicate: () -> String): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder(this)
    sb.append(predicate.invoke())
    return sb.toString()
}
```

**Update 2**

> I wish to write a lambda which accept a string parameter and result the same string as result. How can I write the lambda?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val cc = myAdd({ it + "de" })
    System.out.println(cc)
}

fun myAdd(predicate: (String) -> String): String {
    return predicate.invoke("abc")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In order to write a practice code about lambda, so  I need write that

Comment: Ok, then you don't need the argument. See the update with `predicate.invoke()` @HelloCW

Comment: Thanks!  I hope that I can pass the parameter     `fun mySring(aa:String):String{
        return "Prefix"+aa
    }`

Comment: But in your code `predicate: () -> String)` has no parameter

Comment: It doesn't need a parameter because `{"de"}` doesn't use an argument.

Try
```
    val cc = "abc".myAdd { "de" }
    System.out.println(cc)

Comment: If you would add an argument to the function, you would also need to call invoke with an argument:     sb.append(predicate.invoke("foo"))

Comment: Thanks! So I think that my code `var cc="abc".myAdd{"de"} ` is wrong, I wish to write a lambda which accept a string parameter and result the same string as result. How can I write the lambda?

Comment: And more, can I use  `sb.append(predicate())` instead of  `sb.append(predicate.invoke())` in your code ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest version of your extension function can be:

```
fun String.myAdd(append: (String) -> String): String {
    return this + append(this)
}
```

To invoke your function, you should write:

```
println("Hello, world!".myAdd { 
    "XD"
})
```

And it will print `Hello, world!XD`

Your code doesn't work, because you do not pass to `sb.append` `String`, but object of type `String -> String`. If you want invoke this function, just write `(argument)` after it (or use method `invoke(args)`), and then, your `append` (according to my code above) will be invoked and simply returns String.

Actually, see also that as an argument of your high order function (in my case called `append`) you pass `this` object (in my case string `Hello`).

```
println("Hello".myAdd {
    it.reversed()
}
```

And it will print `HelloolleH`.

Comment: Thanks, there are two 'this' in your code, they point to different object, right? And why is `return this + append(it)` wrong?

Comment: I wish to write a lambda which accept a string parameter and result the same string as result. How can I write the lambda?   Is`{"XD"}` correct ?

Comment: `append` needs to take String as parameter. You can pass any String (I thought you want to pass as argument object you invoked function on), so that's why I wrote "this" (as it's extension function `this` refers to receiver). You cannot use `it` keyword in extension function, because it's not declared. `it` keyword it's special name for one-argument lambdas.

Comment: Lambda `{ "XD" }` is correct. In can be `(Any) -> String` or just `() -> String`. This lambda just returns String when invoked (lambdas always returns the last statement in it).